# Will migrating to a new device work when using EncryptedSharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service, encrypted-shared-preference

I know that EncryptedSharedPreferences use the android keystore to encrypt preferences securely and that the android keystore is tied to the devices hardware I also read that the keystore cannot be backed up like preferences and databases are.
My question is what this means when I am trying to restore my apps settings onto a new device:

Are preferences still backed up in a decrypted manner?

Are they still encrypted and thus unusable on the new device?

should I  exclude EncryptedSharedPreferences from backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you locate the `.xml` file that serves as your `Shared Preferences` file, you'll observe that both the `key` and `value` are encrypted. (The `key` here means the `key` you use when putting `Shared Preferences`, not `MasterKey` for encyrpting). Therefore, if you back up the file, you will get its encrypted version. Since the new device and the `key` are encrypted, you will not be able to access anything and you probably will reach the default state of all `Shared Preferences`. You should exclude `Encrypted Shared Preferences` from the backup. If included, there won't be a `MasterKey` available to decrypt the values on the new device. In conclusion this implies that you won't be able to access any data when installing on a new device.

You can review the warning here.

[Encrypted Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences)

Comment: OK so you basically encrypt shared prefs at the cost of not being able to restore them on a new device

Comment: It's purely for security anyway. If you are storing information that should truly remain confidential It would be a little weird if it could be decrypted on another device, right? :)

Comment: yes, granted, but backups are also encrypted, right. so I guess it would be possible to send the decrypted version of prefs to googles backup server and have it be separately encrypted there. I guess this does in fact compromise security a bit but it would allow for smoother transitions between devices while still preventing anyone with a usb cable from viewing your prefs. But what you say makes total sense for something like a banking app.

Comment: It definitely makes sense for banking applications. By the way, if you want a simpler encyrption, you can encrypt it with a simple algorithm or your own algorithm. You can define a const value for key, and you can decrypt it again on another device. In this case, there is may that your key will be obtained through reverse engineering.